# Изменить кнопку активации/деактивации кликера

Tags: python

В коде стоит сочетание клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> мне нужно чтобы код приводился в действие одной лишь клавишей <kbd>Z</kbd> можно ли как то заменить сочетание <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> на простую клавишу <kbd>Z</kbd> не загружая другую библиотеку?

```py
import time
import mouse
import keyboard

isClicking = False
#функция
def set_clicker():
    global isClicking
    if isClicking:
        isClicking = False
        print("кликер отключен")
    else:    #иначе
        isClicking = True
        print("кликер включен")

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+z',set_clicker)    #keyboard.add_hotkey
#Бесконечный цикл
while True:
    if isClicking:
      mouse.double_click(button="left")
      time.sleep(0.500)
```

Comment: keyboard.add_hotkey('z', set_clicker) а просто z указывать пробовали?

Comment: Я пробовал конечно, но тогда начинает возникать ошибка  "while True:
KeyboardInterrupt" хотя кликер работает, но почему тогда ошибка возникает если кликер работает ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте попробуем вот так сделать:

```
import time
import mouse
import keyboard

isClicking = False

# функция
def set_clicker():
    global isClicking
    if isClicking:
        isClicking = False
        print("кликер отключен")
    else:
        isClicking = True
        print("кликер включен")

keyboard.add_hotkey('z', set_clicker)  # Изменили горячую клавишу на 'z'

try:
    while True:
        if isClicking:
            mouse.double_click(button="left")
            time.sleep(0.500)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nПрограмма завершена.')
```

Comment: Спасибо так все работает без ошибок, , а могли бы вы пояснить что вы исправили ? в чем была ошибка

Comment: С хоткеем думаю и так понятно. А так добавил исключение try...except.  Теперь, если вы нажмете Ctrl + C, программа обработает исключение и выведет сообщение "Программа завершена."

Comment: Благодарю за старания и развернутые ответы с примером кода!

Comment: @Zraurum, спасибо здесь выражается принятием ответа (клик на галочку возле него).